# Самоудаление через реестр

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте!

Вот с сайта откопал, какой путь к реестру нужно, что самоудалить прогу:
"`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`"

Записи в этом разделе указывают на имена файлов, которые должны выполниться один раз во время загрузки системы. Для удаления программы, нужно всего лишь добавить запись с именем файла, который удалит ее или командой del "имя файла"."

Но не могу понять, что делать в Delphi. Вот то, что сам написал:

```
reg:=TRegistry.Create;

reg.RootKey:=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

try
reg.OpenKey('\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce',true);
reg.WriteString('del','del "C:\...\Project2.exe"');
reg.CloseKey;
reg.Free;
except
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Попробуйте слеши продублируйте: вместо \ пишите \\,  например так

   reg.WriteString('del','del ' + StringReplace('"C:\...\Project2.exe"', '\', '\\', [rfReplaceAll]);
2. Уберите try except end и посмотрите какую ошибку выдает - может у вас нет прав на запись в эту ветку.
3. Что записалось в реестр посмотрите.
4. Попробуйте запись в реестр команду вручную и проверьте срабатывает ли он при перезагрузке - этот ключ может быть проигнорирован, если это указано в политике безопасности.
5. Попробуйте писать в реестр такую команду

   cmd /C del /F /Q "C:\RHDSetup.log"

Comment: ОШИБКА: Failed to set data for 'del'

Comment: У меня ваш код работает без проблем, возможно у вас нет прав на запись в эту ветку реестра. Дайте себе права и попробуйте еще раз.<br>
Да, только путь надо правильный указывать конечно, а так да - запись в реестре появляется.<br>
Некоторый антивирусы могут блокировать запись в эту ветку, вроде как вирусная активность :)

Comment: У меня Windows 7 это както влияет на это?!

Блин лемит кончился! Да кстати надо свой создавать порметор или в тот записать где Имя: "По умолчанию"

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить эту команды вручную из консоли, и проверьте правильность его работы <br>
del /F /Q "C:\realtek.log" <br>
/F - удалять если даже файл только для чтения <br>
/Q - удалять не спрашиваю подтверждения <br>
Версия винды, вроде, не должна влиять на работу скрипта

Comment: Да кстати надо свой создавать пораметор(и какой?) или в тот записать где Имя: "По умолчанию"

Comment: Не понимаю! Все в ручную сделал:
Создал строковой параметр DEL и в нем прописал del /F /Q "C:\Users\ЭРИК\Desktop\celf.txt" --> перезагрузил комп и все файл на месте а параметра DEL в реестре нет!!!

Comment: Попробуйте писать в реестр такую команду<br>
cmd /C del /F /Q "C:\RHDSetup.log"

Comment: Нажмите F1 и почитайте в справке.

Answer (score 2):

Для самоудаления лучше всего использовать bat-файл.

```
:1
del /F /Q "C:\prog.exe" || goto :1
del /F /Q "C:\delete_prog.bat"
```

Генерить и запускать его можно прям из программы. 2-я строка будет пытаться удалить `prog.exe` пока запущенный процесс программы не отпустит его. После успешного удаления программы 3-я строка удалит сам bat-файл.

**UPD:** Чтобы процесс удаления работал в фоне без окна консоли в панели задач запускать его нужно через `ShellExecute(0, 'Open', 'C:\delete_prog.bat', nil, nil, SW_HIDE)`